# Regex pattern for parsing this test file?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I am working on a console Application that connects to a Telnet Cisco Switch,
asks for an IP Address and returns the port on the Cisco Switch.

Currently I'm saving the Output of show ip arp 192.168.1.X in a text file like this

```
show ip arp 192.168.1.X
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  192.168.1.X             0   00df.8dfs.a6a3  ARPA   VlanX
cisco-switch#
```

(Infos are changed for security purpose)

Now I need to parse the text file for the Hardware Address and store it in a variable.
Is there any regex pattern to parse it for `XXXX.XXXX.XXXX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below pattern to match `XXXX.XXXX.XXXX`,

```
\b[a-z0-9]{4}(?:\.[a-z0-9]{4}){2}\b
```

I assumed that the Hardware address must contains lowercase letters and numbers.